# Are there stable open source apps that would work well for conferencing, larger meetings or teaching?

Tags: software-recommendation, websites, open-source, office-communicator

with all of this social distancing and work from home stuff I am curious what people use for large meetings? Open source would be preferred, as would stable. I am a teacher and would love to be able to display PP slides and have video.

Thanks!

Comment: here is a link to what you want https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-20-best-linux-video-conferencing-software/ i have no experience with any of them but the other people here might give you some advice about this.

Comment: This might help: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72458/open-source-self-hosted-videoconference-server/72461

Answer (score 1):

[BigBlueButton](https://bigbluebutton.org/) is a stable and useful teaching platform, however, it is not peer to peer. It's a web-based app that runs on a server and has very specific software system requirements.  There are several companies that host installations for educational institutions.

It's got whiteboard and slides support. Unlike teams, it works just as well with Libre Office. Unlike Zoom, it doesn't require anyone to install special software.

Routing system sound through it, however, is slightly fiddly.